# Force a particular array id order to object lookup in Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am using Laravel (and hence eloquent).

I have a very complex, multi union, multi table join lookup in eloquent. It requires a specific ordering via multiple table/child joins. This means that to use the ORM part of laravel is not appropriate, even if the eloquent aspect is.

I have successfully implemented this query, and am returning a set of IDs. As I mentioned, these are ordered correctly.

Laravel has the following methods:

- `$object::find($ids)`
- `$object::whereIn('id', $ids)->get()`

Fundamentally, these responses are identical if these are run with the following arrays:

- `[1,2,3]`
- `[3,2,1]`

i.e: They respond as if ordered by ID.

How can I force the specific order that I pass to it?

I know this can be done in MySQL by:

- `select * from records where id in (3,4,5) order by field(id,4,5,3)`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This leans heavily (well.. it's pretty much the same) on the answer given by @thisiskelvin

Please upvote him instead of this answer (or both)

I created a trait.. which I called `AdvancedModelLookup` in `app\Traits`.

In this I created a slightly modified function from the provided code:

```php
<?

namespace App\Traits;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

trait AdvancedModelLookup
{
    /**
     * This run a query and orders the objects as per a provided array/collection.
     *
     * @param $query Builder
     * @param $field
     * @param $ids Collection|array
     *
     * @return Collection
     */
    public static function getInOrder(Builder $query, string $field, $ids): Collection
    {
        $results = $query->whereIn($field, $ids)->get();

        $reorder = collect([]);
        foreach ($ids as $id) {
            $reorder->push($results->where($field, $id)->first());
        }

        return $reorder;
    }}
```

Now use this trait:

```php
use App\Traits\AdvancedModelLookup;

class SomeObject extends Model
{

    use AdvancedModelLookup;

    //...

}
```

Example use:

```php
$order = [4,5,3];
$query = SomeObject::whereIn('id', $order);

$normal_lookup = $query->get();
$sorted_lookup = SomeObject::getInOrder($query, 'id', $order);

dd($normal_lookup, $sorted_lookup);

// Normal lookup order: 3,4,5
// Sorted lookup order: 4,5,3
```

Note, you could easily expand or create further versions of this style of functionality, such as `pluck()` etc...

This trait gives the quick option to include this on a per-model basis without having to mess with the inheritance of an object.

Answer (score 1):

This is untested, however by creating a [query scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#query-scopes) to do all that is intended, you should be able to complete this.

You can create a [global scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#global-scopes) which you can then apply to any models in your application.

The query scope can take a couple of arguments (excluding the `$query` argument which is required): `$field` & `$values`. In this example, you can pass a field of `id` and values being the array of ids.

It will then perform a normal `where` call, get all the results, then create a new collection of results which are now in the specified order.

**Note**: By returning a collection, the scope emulates the collection returned by the `->get()` method.

```
public function getInOrder($query, $field, $values)
{
    $results = $query->whereIn($field, $values)->get();

    $reorder = collect();

    foreach ($ids as $id) {
        $reorder[] = $results->where($field, $values)->first();
    }

    return $reorder;
}
```

You call this scope function using:

```
$object::getInOrder('id', $ids);
```

**Note**: As this returns a collection, its no longer users the query builder methods, only the collection methods.

Comment: I have just finished testing. Code above needed tweaks, but am sharing now. Great job.

Comment: Glad it helped @elb98rm . Please mark as correct so the question is marked as answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the result's collection to work with it:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-sortby

Comment: Can you give an example? This functionality seems to be "for a collection. sort by property". How do I specify a non "asc" or "desc" order?

Comment: I dont think this answers the question.